# iOS 9.1 Simulator problems

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, simulator, ios9.1

I developed an iOS app on Xcode 6.3 with iOS 8.3 .
Now I update Xcode to 7.1 with iOS 9.1 .
My app work perfectly on iPad with iOS 9.1 
and all the views work perfectly in iPhone with iOS 9.1 expect one view .
With iphone 4s , 5 the problem is `(lldb) with EXC_BAD_ACCESS(Code = 2 ,)`
With iphone 5s , 6 , 6 plus , 6s , 6s plus no error message but the simulators hung all the time with max cpu and ram usage.

note : the implementation of view that causes the problem the same with iPad  but in iPad work perfectly .

Please what the true analysis for the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug in Xcode 7.1 with UITextView , this is stupid bug.

You don't need to ensure that the UITextView holds at least 10 characters. Just adding a default of at least 10 characters to the UITextView in Interface Builder will fix the problem. Then, you can empty the UITextView using code.

Answer (score 0):

this issue comes sometimes if u migrate from xcode 6 to xcode 7.. clean the code and check if the base sdk is proper. 
sometimes this issue also comes in simulator. try running the app in real device.
Also, see if xcode 6 and 7 are not running simultaneously. run only one at a time.

Hope this helps u